# "Make an experience" or "gain an experience"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, idioms

Do you *make an experience* or *gain an experience*? For example,

> I made rewarding volunteering experiences ...
>
> I gained rewarding volunteering experiences ...

Are either acceptable? Is there a finer distinction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Experience* meaning *knowledge or skill from doing something* is used as an uncountable noun and goes with *gain*.

> I gained much **experience** from the job.

*Experience* meaning *something that happens that affects you* is used as a countable noun, but that is another situation altogether.

> He made it an unpleasant **experience** for me.

It is not clear what your example sentences mean and it is best to rewrite them.

Comment: gains experience for oneself. No "an". You gain (uncountable) experience as sum of skill and knowledge obtained from repeating something. You live through an experience, an event that caused a lasting impression (or make one).

Answer (score 3):

Gaining experience would be more appropriate in this context. 
'Making' an experience has the connotation of creating/crafting an experience, which has a different meaning.