# work experience vs work experiences

Tags: word-choice

I often see these 2 terms are used interchangeably.

It's very clear to me that 'work experiences' refers to specific job positions as opposed to the more abstract term work experience, which can be related to skills and the ability.    Just to confirm, is this correct?

Note that this question isn't about differentiating experience(s), but is 'work' oriented.

Comment: I cannot vote to close a question for being a duplicate when the older question is itself  closed, so here's the link with its answers: [Is 'experience' countable or uncountable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199701/is-experience-countable-or-uncountable) but…

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Make an experience" or "gain an experience"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70854/make-an-experience-or-gain-an-experience)

Comment: Another closed question: [When to use word “experience” in a singular form and when in plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300092/when-to-use-word-experience-in-a-singular-form-and-when-in-plural)

Comment: no duplicate question! note that this question stresses on 'work' experience(s), not just experience(s).

Comment: Please give attributed links to researchable examples of the string 'work experiences'. It doesn't seem idiomatic to my ears; I'd expect 'experiences at work' (and if 'work experiences' _is_ rare, then @Mari-Lou A would be quite right to close-vote as a duplicate).

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't correct. The specific job positions that a person has held would be that person's "work history" or "employment history".

"Work experiences" is not a common expression, but it would be understood as referring to things that you have experienced during work; these things could be specific incidents (such as "dealing with a dissatisfied customer" or "facilitating a coworker's project") or specific environments (e.g. "working in a startup" or "working at a family-owned business").

"Work experience" refers to how much and what kind of work someone has done. You are correct to say that it is related to skills and abilities. A person's employment history would give a detailed picture of that person's work experience.

The following thread on UsingEnglish.com is relevant: [work experience / work experiences /single or plural?](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/8045-work-experience-work-experiences-single-or-plural)

Comment: thx. so what u r saying is that work experiences is grammatically correct when referred to employment after employment, but is generally not used as employment after employment. work history or employments should b substitutes?

Comment: @feynman: I am not sure what you mean by "employment after employment". Do you mean like a list of the jobs that somebody has held? That would be called "work history" or "employment history"; you would not say "employments".

Comment: yes, what i mean is a list of jobs